# Z-transform of x[a -n]...where a is int

Tags: z-transform

i try to calculate the $\mathcal z$-transform of $x[a-n]$ (where $n$ is my variable)
i can't find any transform. the best suited transform is $x[-n] \longleftrightarrow X(z^{-1})$
i took the sum definition of the $\mathcal z$-transform but i couldnt find.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to derive the result:

1. Just use the definition of the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform:
   $$\begin{align}\mathcal{x[a-n]}&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[a-n]z^{-n}{\Big|}_{k=a-n}\\
   &=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x[k]z^{k-a}\\
   &=z^{-a}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x[k]z^{k}=z^{-a}X\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\end{align}$$
2. Use the well-known properties of the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform (version 1):
   $$x[n+a]\longleftrightarrow z^aX(z)\\ [n\rightarrow -n\Rightarrow z\rightarrow 1/z]\\
   x[-n+a]\longleftrightarrow z^{-a}X\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$$
3. Use the well-known properties of the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform (version 2):
   $$x[-n]\longleftrightarrow X\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\\ [n\rightarrow n-a \Rightarrow \times\; z^{-a}] \\
   x[-(n-a)]\longleftrightarrow z^{-a}X\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$$

Comment: A reference on the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform might be missing on your very first math term. Otherwise, +