# Convolution & FT properties

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

I have been trying hardly to check if these equalities are true or false. However, I have not been able to conclude anything. Could you help me, please?

$$y[2n]=h[n]\star x[2n] $$

$$\mathfrak{F}(x[-n])e^{-jp\pi Fm}=\mathfrak{F}(x[-n+m]) $$

Comment: Really ? At least be honest and tell us this is your homework. How do you want us to help here ? We don't even know what x, y,h are

Comment: Where I study we don't have to do homework, this is just a proposed problem that I want to know how to do. x[n] and y[n] are two not-specified sequences.

Comment: Please, allow me to rephrase : both properties you're showing are basics, and you should have, before posting this question, respectively look up "discrete convolution" and "Fourier's transform basic properties" on google and figured out what exactly was preventing you to understand those two equations.

Comment: I suppose $y[n]=h[n]\star x[n]$, otherwise it doesn't make much sense. It's common here to show your own efforts, so we can see where you're stuck and how we can best help you.

Comment: The problem is with the 2, that is just the convolution equation. The problem in the first one is that in discrete is not possible to apply the scaling property, otherwise it would be easy by just transforming in both sides.

Comment: I'm with Matt L.: The first statement makes no sense unless we know that $y[n] = h[n] \star x[n]$.  The second question is about a time shift, which you should be able to answer from a table of Fourier transform properties.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because without further specification, this is but a question about the basic properties of the operations that OP is asking about, which bears no value for future readers, as any reader would have to look up these concepts in standard literature  (e.g. Wikipedia) before being able to search for this question. Without a specific question, OP is asking us to write a textbook chapter on the very basics on Convolution and the Fourier Transform.

Comment: I'm sorry, It's the first time I ask anything here. Next time I will do better.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to get you started.

For the first part:

1. Write out the convolution sum for $y[n]=h[n]\star x[n]$
2. Replace $n$ by $2n$, which gives you an expression for $y[2n]$
3. Write out the convolution sum for $h[n]\star x[2n]$
4. Check if both expressions are equal. If you've done everything right, the answer should be 'no' (i.e., they're not equal). If you fail showing this, add your steps to your question and explain what the problem was.

For the second part:

1. Write the Fourier transform of $x[-n]$ in terms of the Fourier transform of $x[n]$, and multiply by $e^{-j2\pi fm}$; that's the left-hand side of the equation.
2. Compute the Fourier transform of the right-hand side. [This answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27955/z-transform-of-xa-n-where-a-is-int/27971#27971) will be helpful (replace $z$ by $e^{j2\pi f}$).
3. Like step 4 above, just that in this case the answer should be 'yes' (i.e., they're equal).

Answer (score 0):

If you make the variable change $2n=m$ you can easily see that $$y[m]=h[m]*x[m]$$ that is obviously different from $$y[m]=h[m/2]*x[m]$$ therefore it's FALSE.

---

The second sentence could be explained by the transposition property $$x[-n]=X(-F)$$ and the property of frequency displacement $$X(F)\cdot e^{(-j·2·\pi·m·F)} \longleftrightarrow x[n-m]$$ After applying that you got that it's TRUE.

PS: I'm your classmate

Comment: A bit of $\LaTeX$ would make your answer much more readable.